# Seaborn scatterplot from a pandas dataframe for 2 columns

Tags: pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe df with:

```
sentiment | topic
1         | 1
-4        | 0
2         | 1
-1        | 0
1         | 0
3         | 1
```

I would like to make a scatter plot to see how the sentiment values line up depending on topic.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_sql_table("df", result)
sns.catplot(x="topic", y="sentiment", order=["0", "1"], data=df)
plt.show()
```

But the plot is empty?

Does Seaborn not get the values from the dataframe correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what the issue is without having the original data, but in the table that you provided it looks like the values in the `topic` column are numeric, not strings. If that's the case, then you shouldn't pass strings to the `order` parameter. If this is the issue, this should work:

```
sns.catplot(x="topic", y="sentiment", order=[0, 1], data=df)
plt.show()
```

If this still doesn't work, you can try removing the `order` parameter altogether and see if that fixes it.